# How to create an rhandsontable with fixed headers?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, rhandsontable

Can someone advise me on how to fix column headers in an `rhandsontable`? Below there is a sample script I have written, but it does not work. It seems that I could not use `hot_cols()` in a proper way. I need help to amend this script or get an alternative one for this task.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)

# Define the UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Fixed Column Headers"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(
        title = "Table with Fixed Column Headers",
        width = 12,
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        status = "primary",
        rHandsontableOutput("table")
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data = iris, readOnly = TRUE, width = "100%", height = "400px") %>%
      hot_cols(colHeaderClassName = "fixed-header")
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Jan. In one of my  earlier questions your help was insightful. I hope you can give a proper solution to this question as well.

Comment: For clarification: Your goal here is that when you scroll the page using the bar on the right hand side, that the table header also scrolls down and remains visible. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, you got the point. The table header should also scroll down when I scroll the page using the RHS bar as well as the mouse's rolling ball.

Comment: But why are you then not using `output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(data = iris, readOnly = TRUE, height = 400)})`? This creates a table of height `400px` which has the desired behaviour.

Comment: Jan, your hint worked well. Appreciate!